# Storing the private key password for auto-mounting SSHFS?

Tags: ssh, key-authentication, sshfs, mate-desktop

I connect to a server via `sshfs` using private/public key pairs. My local key needs a passphrase to use.  **NOTE:** The public key has already been copied to the remote server. I'm looking for a method to cache the credentials for this key!

I want to auto-mount this share at login (to a MATE session), and need a secure way of storing the password for the key (as opposed to the SSH password, since the server does not accept passwords).

Right now the command is:

```
$ sshfs me@mydomain.com:/ /home/me/MyMountPoint
```

But I am prompted for a password to unlock the key. I could make the key not require a password, but if it's safer to use a password protected key and store the password somewhere else, I would favour that over a non-password key.

What would be the recommended way of doing this? If the password file has permissions of `600`, then only my user could see it. But then again, the key should already be `600` and only my user could get at it in the first place.

Is there a best practice for storing the key password for auto-mounting SSHFS?

Comment: @sim: The remote key is installed and working. I can login manually be entering my local key's password. This question is about a safe way to store the password for the local key for automatic use.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. I've added a note to your Q so that this is more explicitly obvious. Do you have these packages installed? `mate-keyring` and `mate-keyring-pam`?

Comment: If you say "password" you talk about the passhrase - right?

Answer (score 4):

Use `ssh-agent` to store the key, then sshfs can use the key from the agent without asking for the passphrase. - Of course you now need to supply the passphrase to add the key to the agent. - [`mate-keyring`](https://github.com/mate-desktop/mate-keyring) might help you with this.

Comment: I would recommend something like gnome-keyring-daemon over mate-keyring. gnome-keyring-daemon is a very common utility, often installed and running by default. It even provides a pam module to unlock the keyring using the login password.

Comment: @Patrick - do you know off hand if that is out of the box wrt to the pam mod or do you have to set that up custom?

Comment: @slm From my experience, on ubuntu & gentoo, if gnome-keyring-daemon is installed, the pam module is installed and configured. But it's entirely up to the distro/package.

Comment: @Patrick - that's the biggest issue with this/these types of Q's they're very distro specific, I'd like to see us develop a more general purpose A to these questions so that we can refer to it. He tagged the Q as mate, but as you've indicated you can mix and match using gnome-keyring-daemon which compounds to the confusion/complexity.

Comment: @slm except it isn't necessarily the goal of stackexchange to provide a howto guide as an answer. It's to provide an answer of how something could be done. If the user runs into an issue trying to accomplish the goal, they can ask another question on the specific issue.

Comment: @Patrick - understood, but on this site anyway we generally strive to give more than just an answer, we like to provide background info when we can so that things are also understood for both the OP & future visitors to the site. I've read enough garbage answers on SO with 50 UV for just a link, I think we can hold ourselves to a higher standard here.

Comment: Is there a way to invoke ssh-add in a way so that the passphrase can be put in a file?

Comment: @Nils - I don't think you want to do that. That defeats the purpose of having keys in the first place.

Comment: @slm it defeats the purpose of having a passphrase - not of having keys.

Comment: @Nils - point taken I mis-stated that comment. You'd get security of the certs in the connection, but the use of those keys would be wide open to anyone that had access to them physically on disk.

Comment: @slm so the solution is somewhere along the way to use a pam-module that registers the passphrase during login in the ssh-agent. I once got that working on CentOS using the Ubuntu guideline for KDE. There I replaced the KDE-login-prompt with a passhrase-promt. But now it does not work any more - that was the background of my question here.

Comment: @Nils - yes a solution to this prob. is something along those lines, IMO, I've been trying to determine the underpinnings of what adds entries to your keyring so that they can be used from boot to boot. That would seem to be along the lines of your idea of putting it in a file, but at least it's in the keyring which can then be locked/unlocked via the screenlocking and such so that it's more secure than simply putting it in a file.

Answer (score 0):

#### seahorse

One method for caching your passphrase is to make use of the application `seahorse`. This is the application that's used by all the distros that are based on GNOME2 & GNOME3. It might go by other names or shortcuts but you should be able to launch it on any of these distros from the command line like so:

```
$ seahorse
```

Once you invoke it you'll be greeted with a GUI like so. Be sure the GUI is selected so that it shows everything "By keyring". It's helpful to keep things straight in this view.

[image: ss #1]

#### Adding a key

Once you've brought up the GUI you'll want to click on the plus icon to add a key, and select "Secure Shell Key from the dialog.

[image: ss #2]

[image: ss #3]

#### Key setup

Now you'll want to define what user this key will be used for and for what machine. This is just a description, but it's helpful when keeping track of your keys in the `$HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys file where it will get used later on. Also it's usually the last field in your

[image: ss #4]

#### Setting the key's passphrase

Next you'll need to provide the passphrase for this key 2 times.

[image: ss #5]  [image: ss #6]

#### Copy .pub key to remote server

At this point the public/private key pair has been created, and has a passphrase. Now you'll need to copy the .pub key to a user's account on a remote server.

[image: ss #7]

#### Authorize the copying of .pub

When you acknowledge the above dialog you'll need to authenticate as userX (tammy in this case) on the remote server (mulder).

[image: ss #8]

#### Login to remote server (mulder)

With the key/pair copied to the remote server (mulder) as userX (tammy) we can now attempt to ssh to this server as this user. Doing this will trigger for the password to get added to the keyring permanently.

[image: ss #9]

#### Adding passphrase permanently

You'll then get prompted for the passphrase, with the option to make it permanently part of the keyring store forever.

**NOTE:** This is critical, doing this will allow you to never have to provide this passphrase ever again. Any time you login to your account and unlock it, you'll be unlocking this keyring, which contains this passphrase.

[image: ss #10]

#### No more passphrase

From now on any time you log in you'll no longer have to provide your passphrase.

#### Confirmation

Besides logging in and out to the remote server (mulder) if you close `seahorse` and reopen it you'll notice an additional "Unlock passphrase" entry now exists in your Login keyring. This was added when you checked the box in the previous dialog.

[image: ss #11]

**NOTE:** I believe you can also add entries manually to store passphrases within your Login keyring too. This would allow for you to store any preexisting SSH key pair passphrases as well.

#### The setup

For this to work I'm using `gnome-keyring` and `gnome-keyring-pam` which facilitate this. An entry such as this in my PAM configuration allows for the Login keyring within `seahorse` to be unlocked when I login and/or unlock my screenlock.

```
$ more /etc/pam.d/passwd
#%PAM-1.0
auth       include  system-auth
account    include  system-auth
password   substack system-auth
-password   optional    pam_gnome_keyring.so use_authtok
password   substack postlogin
```

Notice the 5th line.

#### References

- [How do I set up SSH so I don't have to type my password?](https://superuser.com/questions/8077/how-do-i-set-up-ssh-so-i-dont-have-to-type-my-password)
- [GNOME Keyring - ArchLinux Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GNOME_Keyring)

Comment: OP's private key requires a password. The public key has already been sent to the remote system.

Comment: @Patrick - Michas and I already went over this in a discussion. I would like the OP to confirm this. He probably has but doesn't explicitly say that he has.

Comment: "My local key needs a password to use" "need a secure way of storing the password for the key" "prompted for a password to unlock the key" "I could make the key not require a password". It's very clear

Comment: @Patrick - I added an explicit comment to the Q, asking for this, I see that he "says" something to that effect in his Q, but I'd like him say it explicitly, and explain how. Otherwise we might be chasing ghosts 8-)

Comment: @Patrick - mine too, but it can get cached in a variety of ways on the keyring so that you don't have to provide. That's ultimately what I'd like to see hashed out of this Q/A

Comment: good revision, but a few points: 1) seahorse is simply a GUI to gnome-keyring-daemon. The keyring runs in the background, and will work without seahorse. 2) You do not need to add a new key. The gnome-keyring-daemon will automatically pick up `~/.ssh/id_rsa`. The `/etc/pam.d/password` is actually not used for login. 3) That specific pam file is only for when the user changes their password, so that the login keyring's password will be updated. The applicable pam file is probably something like `/etc/pam.d/system-login`.

Comment: @Patrick - (1) & (2) .. yes I was taking the tactic that you had no key and this was how to do the entire process. I snuck a line in the "Confirmation" section (see the note) trying to mention that you could do just the adding of the passphrase w/o making a key. If I understand this step a bit better I'll add details on how to just add password to your Login keyring.

Comment: @Patrick - regarding `/etc/pam.d/passwd`, OK. I only see the .so for `pam_gnome_keyring.so` in 3 files. `gdm-password`, `/etc/pam.d/gdm-pin`, & `/etc/pam.d/passwd`. My `system-auth` makes no mention of keyring.

Comment: @Patrick - one thing I like with the `seahorse` approach is that all the GNOME platforms are really using this under the hood, so this gives us the ability to cover all the distros with one set of steps. The steps I used worked on Fedora/CentOS/Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

If you are auto-mounting via `autofs` this will be done with the local **root** account.
So generate a root-key without passphrase and establish a trust to the target *account@server.*

Comment: This doesn't solve his problem.  If he wanted a key without a passphrase, he could create the ssh key without one to begin with and not as root.

Comment: @vol7ron Yes. But root keys are propably harder to get at. My presumtion was that his home is inecure e.g. NFS, so in need of a passphrase, while root is normally a local secure fs.

Comment: Would this then be available to any user on the file system?

Comment: @vol7ron If you want, you can grant any user the rights of the original user. That is a mount option for sshfs.